# How to make (split?) 1 dedicated server to 2 or more servers in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine

IS there any way to do make a dedicated servers splitted in ubuntu 18?

FOr example a dedicated server 1Gbps , 128 GB RAM

And i want to make it : 300-400-300 Mbps, 32-64-32 GB ram 3 servers respectively.

Its enough to say a program or similar question? I searched and found not many thing.

Comment: You can use VMs and/or containers...

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to run 3 Ubuntu servers as virtual machines? Either under VirtualBox, VMWare, or perhaps qemu?

Comment: YEs virtual machine. Different ip. Different specs. 
is there a complete document to do that in ubuntu?

Comment: Are you sure you are up to this task? Virtualization is complex, there are tons of way to do it, and there is no "one fits all" solution.